# What percentage of new users who have their questions closed actually visit /help/closed-questions?

Tags: support, statistics

Currently, when a question is closed, it gets a banner that includes the line:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/current/edit).

The "help center" link goes to /help/closed-questions, which gives an explanation of how the close and reopen system works.

Are there statistics on how often the OP actually clicks through to the help center after getting their question closed, specifically new users (say, first question, or first closed question)? Would it be possible for staff to get these stats?

Comment: There must be an (evil) tracking cookie somewhere ;)

Comment: Actually  you wouldn't need it on a site you run yourself